# How to connect to a hidden network with nmcli?

Tags: networking, wifi, networkmanager, nmcli, 802.1x

I can connect to a hidden network knowing the SSID that the router/hotspot has set:

```
CONNECTION_NAME=hidden-wifi
INTERFACE=wlp0s20u1
nmcli con add type wifi ifname $INTERFACE con-name $CONNECTION_NAME ssid $SSID
nmcli con modify 802-11-wireless.bssid $CONNECTION_NAME
nmcli -p con up id $CONNECTION_NAME
```

It is not possible to have a blank `ssid` with non blank `bssid`:

```
nmcli con edit hidden-wifi
nmcli> remove 802-11-wireless.ssid 
nmcli> set 802-11-wireless.bssid 11:22:33:44:55:66
nmcli> save
Error: connection verification failed: 802-11-wireless.ssid: property is missing
```

1. **Is it possible to connect with `nmcli` to a open hidden wifi without providing the SSID?** (but the BSSID instead).
2. If so **how to connect with `nmcli` without providing a  password?**

PS: I am already able to connect with `wpa_supplicant`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always need an SSID. A hidden network is not a network without SSID, it's a network that doesn't broadcast it's SSID (unless solicitated).

You don't need anything special with hidden Wi-Fi networks.